# display lists dynamically using dynamic routes

Tags: node.js, ejs

i have 3 routes(home,work,other). i want to display pages based on the route.
i have written something like this

```
app.get("/user/:page",function(req,res){
  var lname = req.params.page
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,data){
      lists.findOne({userid:req.user._id},function(err,data){
        var d = []
        if(lname==="home")
        d = data.home
        else if(lname==="work")
        d = data.work
        else if(lname==="other")
        d = data.other
        console.log(d);
        res.render("list",{day:lname,listItem:d})
      })
    })
  }
  else{
  res.redirect("/login")
  }
})
```

but this route is getting called 2 times an the req..params.page value is changing, i dont know why.
what is the problem with my code?